# Powershell command to extract list of customers who did the Microsoft cloud agreement

Tags: powershell, ms-office

Microsoft is applying a new process, where customer should provide their acceptance to MS partner as per the link below:

[MS Confirm-Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/confirm-consent)

As a Partner-Center admin, I got the task to extract a list that contains the customers that accepted the Microsoft Cloud Agreement.

Extracting the customer list from partner center doesn't show whether agreement is done or not.
I also tried power shell commands below:

```
Get-MsolPartnerContract -All | fl

Get-MsolCompanyInformation -TenantId xyxyxyxyxy-xyxy-xyxy-xyxy-xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy
```

but neither of them showed the Microsoft Cloud Agreement.

Any one got an idea on how to do that or a command that can show Microsoft Cloud Agreement for a tenant ID?

Answer (score 0):

A module exists that allows you to connect to PartnerCenter via PowerShell. You will need to make sure you have the correct permissions assigned to your partner user or application prior to connecting.
Here's a link to the repository:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Partner-Center-PowerShell

It contains many commands, but the one to get confirmation of customer acceptance provided previously is Get-PartnerCustomerAgreement

You'll need to write a script to do this for each of your customer tenants as the command does not return a list as you described.

In addition to PowerShell, The Partner Center SDK can be used as an automated approach to confirm customers have accepted the MCA.

I have provided a link below to MS documentation on how to do that. I have tested this and confirmed the response includes the templateId, dateAgreed and other information.

If you're not already using the Partner Center SDK, it can take a little time to get the authentication setup, but can accomplish what you are needing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-confirmation-of-customer-consent